# Firebase session cookie

Tags: python, firebase-authentication

I am having an issue where I can't seem to find the solution. I've seen so many SO topics with the same question but really not one answer has helped me.

I am managing session cookie on the server side with Firebase Auth. The problem I am having is that, the request to sessionLogin to set the httpOnly cookie works great but **any subsequent request to protected routes won't carry over the session cookie.**

My code is exact the same [as this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) with only one difference which is the name of the session cookie that I've changed to __session instead of session:

```py
# Set cookie policy for session cookie.            
response.set_cookie(
                '__session', session_cookie, expires=expires, httponly=True, secure=True)
redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Why sessions cookie are not being carried over to any other route other than the sessionLogin?

Comment: Have you tried your code without changing the name of the session cookie?

Comment: Yes I have and same results. 

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira, do you have any ideas?

Comment: What is the value for expires?

Comment: I set 120 minutes in the expires variable